# Why linear model assumes independence among inputs

Tags: machine-learning, independence, linear-regression

First come across this statement in the [MIT Machine Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/mlp.html) book:

> Linear models also have the obvious defect that the model capacity is
>   limited to linear functions, so **the model cannot understand the
>   interaction between any two input variables.**

Googled this, and also found on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-limitations-of-linear-regression-modeling-in-data-analysis/answer/Ed-Caruthers?srid=u343d) that (in describing linear model assumptions):

> Are the inputs really independent of each other?

I seem to have the feeling that to catch dependencies among inputs, there should be terms like $x_1x_2$ instead of just separated $x_1, x_2,...,x_n.$ But I need a more concrete explanation. Intuitive explanations would be preferred.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan The assumption doesn't look obvious/trivial to me. I want an explanation of it.

Comment: The assumption is nearly always false. We don't assume the variables are independent because it's true, we assume it because, among other things, it results in a model that's easy to learn, easy to interpret, and not much at risk of overfitting.